# IOS 7 for non developers

Tags: app-store-connect, ios

Can people without an Apple developers account try the beta versions of iOS 7?

Comment: Edited this Q&A to be one question rather than two.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone can run the beta, provided they're a member of Apple's [iOS developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/), which costs $99/year to join.

Comment: The question explicitly asks about people without developer accounts.

Answer (score 2):

No, participation in the [iOS 7 beta](https://developer.apple.com/ios7/) is limited those with Apple iOS developer accounts. Keep in mind that signing up for the account and using the beta subjects you to a non-disclosure agreement that limits your ability to discuss the beta.

Comment: I'm sure there are others (tech journalists, for instance) who get to see iOS 7 before it goes live, but under their own NDA. In any event, you're right that the general public can't just download a beta.

Answer (score 0):

The official version of iOS 7 is not released yet. Only when you have a developer's ID ($99/yr) can you install the beta version of iOS 7.

Though you can download the leaked developer's version online and install it on a jailbroken device, it is not recommended and is illegal.

Comment: The device doesn't need to be jailbroken to installe a version of iOS 7 - sadly but true.

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of folks mentioned, you can after paying the 100 bucks developer account.

But i do not recommend it, it's really not for primary devices and/or consumer usage.

You wouldn't be satisfied with the user experience, it's really not finished yet.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible - but I will not go into how.

$99 a year is not that expensive, so it is foolish to "cheat"

Comment: I don't the question is asking for warez sites (and if it is, it's not a question that's welcome here). There is plenty of software that *can* be legitimately tried in beta form by people who aren't registered developers. The OP is asking if there is a way to do this with iOS 7.

Comment: It is possible to install iOS 7 without a personal developer account - the *. Ipsw file you can get from a registered developer, where you can choose to register the iPhones/iPads UUID or not, because it is not necessary - but how to install/upgrade without a developer account, I'll not go into, because I don't like it, and I'm not allowed to do it. But it doesn't change the fact that it is possible.